# CiviCRM & Joomla Username Check Availability

Tags: profile, joomla

I am trying to get CiviCRM (5.3.0) and Joomla (3.8.10) working with the Username Check Availability link. I have checked the code and found the following:

`<a id="checkavailability" href="#" onclick="return false;"><strong>Check Availability</strong></a>`

I cannot figure out if I turned something off or is there a problem with the Joomla integation? The accounts are being created in Joomla when registering by using a Profile.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the CiviCRM 5.12.3 and Joomla 3.9.5 combination, the issue is fixed.